# Добавление label инпута в email woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый день. Нужно добавить вывод label для инпута в письмо с заказом. Лейблы добавляю стандартно

```
 $fields['billing']['billing_city']['label'] = 'Город';
```

В письме, что приходит на почту, выводится лишь название города. Пробовал вариант [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986388/how-to-change-woocommerce-customer-details-labels-in-email)
, но результата это не дает

Comment: Правильно, потому что это для изменения существующих полей. Формирование письма происходит в шаблонах wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/ Если вы хотите внести изменения в письмо, надо копировать нужный шаблон в свою тему, и править его. Или использовать хуки в нём прописанные.

Comment: @KAGG Design, скопировал 2 шаблона. Как я понимаю, мне нужен хук  WC_Emails::customer_details(), а именно файл email-customer-details.php, но я никак не пойму почему он не работает в моем случае